# Does a closed form expression of this series exist?

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations, closed-form, fibonacci-numbers

I have a [function](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1%2Fx) $y=\frac{1}{x}$. If $x = 1$, then $y = 1$; if $x = 2$, then $y = 0.5$, etc. If I wanted to add the previous term to the current term, I would have $x = 1.5$, $x = 2.167$ etc.

The terms in the sequence could be represented as:

Term 1:$\ x+\frac{1}{x}$

Term 2:$\ x+\frac{1}{x+\frac{1}{x}}+\frac{1}{x}$

Term 3:$\ x+\frac{1}{x+\frac{1}{x}}+\frac{1}{x+\frac{1}{x+\frac{1}{x}}+\frac{1}{x}}+\frac{1}{x}$

If the initial value was set to $x = 1$, the sequence would continue $x = 2$, $x = 2.5$, $x = 2.9$, with the [recurrence relationship](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=a_n%20%3D%20a_%28n%20-%201%29%20%2B%201%2F%28a_%28n%20-%201%29%29) $a_n =a_{n-1} +\frac{1}{a_{n-1} }$ .

When I plot the first $1000$ numbers in the sequence, they converge to fit a power law line of best fit$\ 1.4234x^{0.4993}$, but I have no idea why. Shown below is the plot of the first $1000$ numbers and the line of best fit:

[image: Plot of first 1000 numbers and line of best fit]

Does a closed form representation of this sequence exist? Something like a function of the Fibonacci numbers, or a sum of series, or a sum of series within a sum of series?
Many thanks!

Comment: It seems like you want to study the recurrence relation $a_{n+1}:=f(a_n)$ with $a_0:=x$ and $f(y):=y+\frac1y$.

Comment: If @nejimban is right, note $a_{n+1}^2-a_n^2>2$.

Comment: $a_{n+1}-a_n=\frac{a_{n+1}-a_n}{(n+1)-n}=\frac{1}{a_n}\,\, \Rightarrow \,\, \frac{d a_n}{dn}\approx \frac{1}{a_n}\,\,\Rightarrow\,\, a_n\sim\sqrt2\sqrt n$

Comment: You may look [here](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/journals/JIS/VOL12/Kimberling/kimberling56.html)

Comment: Amazing thank you everyone for your help! They've put me on the right path now :)